# How do I extract an object from a promise?

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I'm trying get some information out of a nosql database and then read that information through my template engine (handlebars), But I have no idea how to do it

all i'm getting is this message: 
[image]

here's some of the code I wrote thinking it could work

```
let blogPosts = blog.find().where().exec(function(err, blogInfo){
    return blogInfo
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    res.render("blog-home", {blogposts: blogPosts})
});
```

thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To extract an object from a promise you have to wait for the promise to finish.
You do it by using ".then" on the promise.

```
let blogPosts = blog.find().where().exec(function(err, blogInfo){
    return blogInfo
});

router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    blogPosts.then(function (posts) {
        res.render("blog-home", {blogposts: posts});
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

You have to wait for the promise to resolve and *then* render the template, *once the value is there*.

```
router.get('/', function(req, res) {
    let blogPostsPromise = blog.find().where().exec(function(err, blogInfo) {
        return blogInfo
    });  

    blogPostsPromise
       .then(blogPosts => res.render("blog-home", { blogposts: blogPosts }))
       .catch(next);
});
```